# I have used some code to fix undefined variable and undefined index but now database fields are empty

Tags: php

**This is my query**

```html
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","student_information");

 if ($connection->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
 }


 $sql = "INSERT INTO course_details (Student_ID,Admitted_Date,Academic_Year,Course,Profile_Picture)
    VALUES ('$student_id','$admitted_date','$academic_year','$course','$profile_picture');";

 $sql .= "INSERT INTO personal_details (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,DOB,Gender,NIC,Nationality,Religion,Race)
    VALUES ('$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$nic','$nationality','$religion','$race');";

 $sql .= "INSERT INTO contact_details (P_Add_Line1,P_Add_Line2,P_Add_Line3,City,Email,T_Add_Line1,T_Add_Line2,T_Add_Line3,stu_con_home,Stu_Con_Mobile1,Stu_Con_Mobile2,P_Con_Home,P_Con_Mobile1,P_Con_Mobile2)
    VALUES ('$p_add_line1','$p_add_line2','$p_add_line3','$city','$email','$t_add_line1','$t_add_line2','$t_add_line3','$stu_con_home','$stu_con_mobile1','$stu_con_mobile2','$p_con_home','$p_con_mobile1','$p_con_mobile2');";
    
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO academic_details (O_Admi_No,O_Year,O_Subject1,O_Grade1,O_Subject2,O_Grade2,O_Subject3,O_Grade3,O_Subject4,O_Grade4,O_Subject5,O_Grade5,O_Subject6,O_Grade6,O_Subject7,O_Grade7,O_Subject8,O_Grade8,O_Subject9,O_Grade9,A_Admi_No,A_Year,A_Subject1,A_Grade1,A_Subject2,A_Grade2,A_Subject3,A_Grade3,A_Subject4,A_Grade4,Z_Score)
    VALUES ('$o_admi_no','$o_year','$o_subject1','$o_grade1','$o_subject2','$o_grade2','$o_subject3','$o_grade3','$o_subject4','$o_grade4','$o_subject5','$o_grade5','$o_subject6','$o_grade6','$o_subject7','$o_grade7','$o_subject8','$o_grade8','$o_subject9','$o_grade9','$a_admi_no','$a_year','$a_subject1','$a_grade1','$a_subject2','$a_grade2','$a_subject3','$a_grade3','$a_subject4','$a_grade4','$z_score');";      

 $sql .= "INSERT INTO extra_curricular_activities (School_Level,Zonal_Level,District_Level,Provincial_Level,National_Level,International_Level,Current_Activities)
    VALUES ('$school_level','$zonal_level','$district_level','$provincial_level','$national_level','$international_level','$current_activities')";

 /*$sql = "INSERT INTO student_details (Student_ID,Admitted_Date,Academic_Year,Course,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,DOB,Gender,NIC,Nationality,Religion,Race,P_Add_Line1,P_Add_Line2,P_Add_Line3,City,Email,T_Add_Line1,T_Add_Line2,T_Add_Line3,Stu_Con_Home,Stu_Con_Mobile1,Stu_Con_Mobile2,P_Con_Home,P_Con_Mobile1,P_Con_Mobile2,O_Admi_No,O_Year,O_Subject1,O_Grade1,O_Subject2,O_Grade2,O_Subject3,O_Grade3,O_Subject4,O_Grade4,O_Subject5,O_Grade5,O_Subject6,O_Grade6,O_Subject7,O_Grade7,O_Subject8,O_Grade8,O_Subject9,O_Grade9,A_Admi_No,A_Year,A_Subject1,A_Grade1,A_Subject2,A_Grade2,A_Subject3,A_Grade3,A_Subject4,A_Grade4,Z_Score,School_Level,Zonal_Level,District_Level,Provincial_Level,National_Level,International_Level,Current_Activities) 

   VALUES ('$student_id','$admitted_date','$academic_year','$course','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$nic','$nationality','$religion','$race','$p_add_line1','$p_add_line2','$p_add_line3','$city','$email','$t_add_line1','$t_add_line2','$t_add_line3','$stu_con_home','$stu_con_mobile1','$stu_con_mobile2','$p_con_home','$p_con_mobile1','$p_con_mobile2','$o_admi_no','$o_year','$o_subject1','$o_grade1','$o_subject2','$o_grade2','$o_subject3','$o_grade3','$o_subject4','$o_grade4','$o_subject5','$o_grade5','$o_subject6','$o_grade6','$o_subject7','$o_grade7','$o_subject8','$o_grade8','$o_subject9','$o_grade9','$a_admi_no','$a_year','$a_subject1','$a_grade1','$a_subject2','$a_grade2','$a_subject3','$a_grade3','$a_subject4','$a_grade4','$z_score','$school_level','$zonal_level','$district_level','$provincial_level','$national_level','$international_level','$current_activities')";*/

 if ($connection->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Submitted Successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " .$sql."<br>". $connection->error;
 }

 $connection->close();
```

I'm new to the php. I created multiple forms. when i click submit button show "submitted successfully".And I create multi query for insert data to different five tables.

When creating database connection I have error as "undefined variable in...".After I fix that Problem I have another error "undefined index in...".then I fixed it but again shows "undefined variable in..." error.

So I used following code to fix both undefined index and undefined variable error. But now when I submit data that tables are not updated well. Two tables are correctly filled.(contact_details table,extra_curricular_activity table). One table filled without two fields(academic_details table,Z_Score field and A_Grade1 field). Other two tables are empty all fields.but add new row when the click submit button.(course details table,personal_details table)

That empty fields of the database and error fields are the same..so how can I fixed this

**I used following code to fix undefined variable and undefined index**

```html
$profile_picture = isset( $_POST['profile_picture'] )? $_POST['profile_picture']: false;
$student_id = isset( $_POST['student_id'] )? $_POST['student_id']: false;
$admitted_date = isset( $_POST['admitted_date'] )? $_POST['admitted_date']: false;
$academic_year = isset( $_POST['academic_year'] )? $_POST['academic_year']: false;
$course = isset( $_POST['course'] )? $_POST['course']: false;
$first_name = isset( $_POST['first_name'] )? $_POST['first_name']: false;
$middle_name = isset( $_POST['middle_name'] )? $_POST['middle_name']: false;
$last_name = isset( $_POST['last_name'] )? $_POST['last_name']: false;
$dob = isset( $_POST['dob'] )? $_POST['dob']: false;
$gender = isset( $_POST['gender'] )? $_POST['gender']: false;
$nic = isset( $_POST['nic'] )? $_POST['nic']: false;
$nationality = isset( $_POST['nationality'] )? $_POST['nationality']: false;
$religion = isset( $_POST['religion'] )? $_POST['religion']: false;
$race = isset( $_POST['race'] )? $_POST['race']: false;
$a_grade1 = isset( $_POST['a_grade1'] )? $_POST['a_grade1']: false;
$z_score = isset( $_POST['z_score'] )? $_POST['z_score']: false;
```

Comment: The insert query please!

Comment: Now I attached query...how can I fixed this problem

Comment: I don't see any code errors. So, try changing the `: false` with another text, like `: 'Variable is empty'`, and test again.

Comment: It's not working what can I do now??/